# How to set bydefault kendoui grid index order

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to set by default index order in ascending,currently it showing random.
My demo code is.

```
<?php
        // For transfer the data from one page to another page
        $transportData = new Transport(false);
        // read($url, $data=null, $type='POST', $dataType='', $contentType='',  $cache=false)
        $transport = $transportData->read($this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'ObjectTypes/lists')), $this->ObjectType->indexFields, 'POST', '', 'application/json');
        $schemaModel = new SchemaModel('ID', false);

        // Format to add field:
        $model = $schemaModel->addSchemaField('Code');
        $model = $schemaModel->addSchemaField('Name');

        $schema = $schemaModel->createSchema($model);  // create schema with data, errors, model, total.

        $gridDataSource = new GridDataSource($schema, $transport, '', false); //($schema, $transport='', $data='', $inline=true)
        $dataSource = $gridDataSource->addProperty('pageSize', 20);
        $dataSource = $gridDataSource->addProperty('serverPaging', true);
        $dataSource = $gridDataSource->addProperty('serverSorting', true);


        $name = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
         $name->field('Name')
              ->headerTemplate('<b>Name</b>')
              ->title('Name');



        // Creating Grid with Sort functionality, Pagination, Filter functionality, Column Reorder functionality, Column Resize functionality, Column Group functionality..

        $kendoGrid = new KendoGrid('ObjectType', $dataSource, '', false);
        $grid = $kendoGrid->get();
        $grid->addColumn($code, $name, $command);

        echo $grid->render();
    ?>
</div>
```

so please suggest me how to add property into addcolumn to set order.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set it on the data source. Not sure, what is the `GridDataSource` class, but I would suggest calling:

```
$gridDataSource->addProperty('sort', '[{"field":"Name","dir":"asc"}]');
```

or if you are json_encoding values in `addProperty` method:

```
$gridDataSource->addProperty('sort', array('field' => 'Name', 'dir' => 'asc'));
```